# Откуда берётся значение ширины ячейки?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Явное задание ширины последнего столбца не даёт никакого результата.

```css
.playlist_box {
  max-width: 940px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  right: 2.5%;
  z-index: 10;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  color: #414141;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-collapse: separate;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17);
}

.playlist_box::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  right: 10px;
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 10px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
}

.playlist_box th {
  font-family: "Montserrat-bold";
}

.playlist_box td {
  vertical-align: middle;
  font: bold 0.875em "Montserrat-regular";
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd
}

.row-1 {
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-align: left;
}

.row-1>.col-2 {
  padding-left: 4.25531914893617%;
}

.playlist_box_row:not(.row-1) th {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

[class*="col-"] {
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.col-1 {
  width: 4.25531914893617%;
}

.col-2,
.col-3,
.col-4 {
  width: 23.40425531914894%;
}

.col-5 {
  width: 6.382978723404255%;
}

.download_track {
  width: 40px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<tr class="playlist_box_row row-1">
  <th colspan="2" class="col-2">Name</th>
  <th class="col-3">Artist</th>
  <th class="col-4">Album</th>
  <th class="col-5">Time</th>
</tr>
<tr class="playlist_box_row">
  <th class="col-1">1</th>
  <td class="col-2">It's Been Awhile</td>
  <td class="col-3">Staind</td>
  <td class="col-4">Break The Cycle</td>
  <td class="col-5">4:25</td>
  <td class="download_track">
    <a href="#" class="download">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="12px" height="15px">
<path fill-rule="evenodd"  fill="rgb(181, 11, 30)"
 d="M6.000,11.000 L11.000,6.000 L8.000,6.000 L8.000,-0.000 L4.000,-0.000 L4.018,6.000 L1.000,6.000 L6.000,11.000 ZM-0.000,13.000 L-0.000,15.000 L12.000,15.000 L12.000,11.000 L10.000,11.000 L10.000,13.000 L2.000,13.000 L2.000,11.000 L-0.000,11.000 L-0.000,13.000 Z"/>
</svg>
    </a>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr class="playlist_box_row">
  <th class="col-1">2</th>
  <td class="col-2">Bodies</td>
  <td class="col-3">Drowning Pool</td>
  <td class="col-4">Sinner</td>
  <td class="col-5">3:22</td>
  <td class="download_track">
    <a href="#" class="download">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="12px" height="15px">
<path fill-rule="evenodd"  fill="rgb(181, 11, 30)"
 d="M6.000,11.000 L11.000,6.000 L8.000,6.000 L8.000,-0.000 L4.000,-0.000 L4.018,6.000 L1.000,6.000 L6.000,11.000 ZM-0.000,13.000 L-0.000,15.000 L12.000,15.000 L12.000,11.000 L10.000,11.000 L10.000,13.000 L2.000,13.000 L2.000,11.000 L-0.000,11.000 L-0.000,13.000 Z"/>
</svg>
    </a>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr class="playlist_box_row">
  <th class="col-1">3</th>
  <td class="col-2">Savior</td>
  <td class="col-3">Rise Againts</td>
  <td class="col-4">Appeal To Reason</td>
  <td class="col-5">3:58</td>
  <td class="download_track">
    <a href="#" class="download">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="12px" height="15px">
<path fill-rule="evenodd"  fill="rgb(181, 11, 30)"
 d="M6.000,11.000 L11.000,6.000 L8.000,6.000 L8.000,-0.000 L4.000,-0.000 L4.018,6.000 L1.000,6.000 L6.000,11.000 ZM-0.000,13.000 L-0.000,15.000 L12.000,15.000 L12.000,11.000 L10.000,11.000 L10.000,13.000 L2.000,13.000 L2.000,11.000 L-0.000,11.000 L-0.000,13.000 Z"/>
</svg>
    </a>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr class="playlist_box_row">
  <th class="col-1">4</th>
  <td class="col-2">Through Glass</td>
  <td class="col-3">Stone Sour</td>
  <td class="col-4">Come Whatever May</td>
  <td class="col-5">3:58</td>
  <td class="download_track">
    <a href="#" class="download">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="12px" height="15px">
<path fill-rule="evenodd"  fill="rgb(181, 11, 30)"
 d="M6.000,11.000 L11.000,6.000 L8.000,6.000 L8.000,-0.000 L4.000,-0.000 L4.018,6.000 L1.000,6.000 L6.000,11.000 ZM-0.000,13.000 L-0.000,15.000 L12.000,15.000 L12.000,11.000 L10.000,11.000 L10.000,13.000 L2.000,13.000 L2.000,11.000 L-0.000,11.000 L-0.000,13.000 Z"/>
</svg>
    </a>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr class="playlist_box_row">
  <th class="col-1">5</th>
  <td class="col-2">Far Away</td>
  <td class="col-3">Nickelback</td>
  <td class="col-4">All The Night Reason</td>
  <td class="col-5">3:58</td>
  <td class="download_track">
    <a href="#" class="download">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="12px" height="15px">
<path fill-rule="evenodd"  fill="rgb(181, 11, 30)"
 d="M6.000,11.000 L11.000,6.000 L8.000,6.000 L8.000,-0.000 L4.000,-0.000 L4.018,6.000 L1.000,6.000 L6.000,11.000 ZM-0.000,13.000 L-0.000,15.000 L12.000,15.000 L12.000,11.000 L10.000,11.000 L10.000,13.000 L2.000,13.000 L2.000,11.000 L-0.000,11.000 L-0.000,13.000 Z"/>
</svg>
    </a>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @Zicrael для этого необязательно было писать в двух местах одновременно, достаточно было оставить комментарий только под вашим вариантом ответа.

Answer (score 0):

общая ширина всех ячеек(кроме последней), заданная через проценты равняется где-то 84% - оставшиеся на последнюю )

распределите правильно ширину, в первых 5-ти

Возможно Вам поможет calc(% - px) - распределите 40px (от других ячеек)

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался. Просто поменял свойство для 2-3-4 колонок с width на max-width.

Answer (score 0):

Хорошее решение на `flex` будет таким:

`css`:

```
.playlist_box_row {
  display: flex;
}

.col-1 {
  width: 4%;
}

.col-2,
.col-3,
.col-4 {
  width: 27%;
}

.col-5 {
  width: 11%;
}

.download_track {
  width: 4%;
}
```

`html`:

```
<div class="playlist_box_row ">
  <div class="col-1"> </div>
  <div class="col-2">Name</div>
  <div class="col-3">Artist</div>
  <div class="col-4">Album</div>
  <div class="col-5">Time</div>
</div>
<div class="playlist_box_row">
  <div class="col-1">1</div>
  <div class="col-2">It's Been Awhile</div>
  <div class="col-3">Staind</div>
  <div class="col-4">Break The Cycle</div>
  <div class="col-5">4:25</div>
  <div class="download_track">
    <a href="#" class="download">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="12px" height="15px">
<path fill-rule="evenodd"  fill="rgb(181, 11, 30)"
 d="M6.000,11.000 L11.000,6.000 L8.000,6.000 L8.000,-0.000 L4.000,-0.000 L4.018,6.000 L1.000,6.000 L6.000,11.000 ZM-0.000,13.000 L-0.000,15.000 L12.000,15.000 L12.000,11.000 L10.000,11.000 L10.000,13.000 L2.000,13.000 L2.000,11.000 L-0.000,11.000 L-0.000,13.000 Z"/>
</svg>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="playlist_box_row">
  <div class="col-1">2</div>
  <div class="col-2">Bodies</div>
  <div class="col-3">Drowning Pool</div>
  <div class="col-4">Sinner</div>
  <div class="col-5">3:22</div>
  <div class="download_track">
    <a href="#" class="download">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="12px" height="15px">
<path fill-rule="evenodd"  fill="rgb(181, 11, 30)"
 d="M6.000,11.000 L11.000,6.000 L8.000,6.000 L8.000,-0.000 L4.000,-0.000 L4.018,6.000 L1.000,6.000 L6.000,11.000 ZM-0.000,13.000 L-0.000,15.000 L12.000,15.000 L12.000,11.000 L10.000,11.000 L10.000,13.000 L2.000,13.000 L2.000,11.000 L-0.000,11.000 L-0.000,13.000 Z"/>
</svg>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Структурировано, не путаясь в десятых от %.

Пример: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r2ak6yp7/1/)

Comment: Такой вариант мне не подходит, потому что у меня 6 колонок, а в вашем ответе 100% ширины уходит на 5 колонок. А от десятичных значений я отказываться не буду, т.к. % в конечном итоге браузером будут переведены в px и мне нужно точное значение.

Comment: А как вы смотрите на вариант с меньшим количеством кода?
https://jsfiddle.net/r2ak6yp7/1/

Comment: В данном примере меня интересует только табличный вариант. Меньше не значит лучше.

Comment: Как скажете, но табличная вёрстка уже одной ногой в прошлом. Любой вам скажет что `flex` лучше во всём :)

Comment: Если наплевать на семантику, то я с вами соглашусь, но в моём случае этим пренебрегать не стану. Дивы не влияют на семантику кода и в дальнейшем это скажется на ранжирование сайта.

Comment: Почему `flex` нарушает семантику?

Comment: Какое значение имеет div с точки зрения семантики? Это просто блок и ничего больше. Тут и говорить не о чем

Comment: Пусть будет по вашему:)